# OpenGL 2.0 Setting different color for a cube

Tags: opengl-es

I am trying to draw a cube with different colors on each face using OpenGL ES 2.0. I can only draw a cube in one color now. I knew I need to use VertexAttribPointer in this case instead of Uniform, but I probably added them wrongly. Screen shows nothing after I implement my code. Here is my code, can anybody give me a hand? Thank you so much!!!

```
public class MyCube {
private FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;
private ShortBuffer drawListBuffer;
private ShortBuffer[] ArrayDrawListBuffer;
private FloatBuffer colorBuffer;

private int mProgram;

//For Projection and Camera Transformations
private final String vertexShaderCode =
        // This matrix member variable provides a hook to manipulate
        // the coordinates of the objects that use this vertex shader
        "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;" +
                "attribute vec4 vPosition;" +
                "void main() {" +
                // the matrix must be included as a modifier of gl_Position
                // Note that the uMVPMatrix factor *must be first* in order
                // for the matrix multiplication product to be correct.
                "  gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * vPosition;" +
                "}";

// Use to access and set the view transformation
private int mMVPMatrixHandle;

private final String fragmentShaderCode =
        "precision mediump float;" +
                "uniform vec4 vColor;" +
                "void main() {" +
                "  gl_FragColor = vColor;" +
                "}";

// number of coordinates per vertex in this array
static final int COORDS_PER_VERTEX = 3;
float cubeCoords[] = {
        -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f,   // front top left 0
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f,   // front bottom left 1
        0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f,   // front bottom right 2
        0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f,  // front top right 3
        -0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f,   // back top left 4
        0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f,   // back top right 5
        -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,   // back bottom left 6
        0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  // back bottom right 7
        };


// Set color with red, green, blue and alpha (opacity) values
float color[] = { 0.63671875f, 0.76953125f, 0.22265625f, 1.0f };
float red[] = { 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
float blue[] = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };

private short drawOrder[] = {
                                0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3,//front
                                0, 4, 5, 0, 5, 3, //Top
                                0, 1, 6, 0, 6, 4, //left
                                3, 2, 7, 3, 7 ,5, //right
                                1, 2, 7, 1, 7, 6, //bottom
                                4, 6, 7, 4, 7, 5};//back (order to draw vertices)

final float[] cubeColor =
        {
                // Front face (red)
                       1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
                        1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
                        1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
                        1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
                        1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
                        1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,

                // Top face (green)
                        0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
                        0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
                        0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
                        0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
                        0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
                        0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,

                // Left face (blue)
                       0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
                        0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
                        0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
                        0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
                        0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
                        0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,

                // Right face (yellow)
                       1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
                        1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
                        1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
                        1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
                        1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
                        1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,

                // Bottom face (cyan)
                       0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
                        0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
                        0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
                        0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
                        0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
                        0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,

                // Back face (magenta)
                       1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
                        1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
                        1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
                        1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
                        1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
                        1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f
        };


public MyCube() {
    // initialize vertex byte buffer for shape coordinates
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(
            // (# of coordinate values * 4 bytes per float)
            cubeCoords.length * 4);
    bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    vertexBuffer = bb.asFloatBuffer();
    vertexBuffer.put(cubeCoords);
    vertexBuffer.position(0);

    // initialize byte buffer for the draw list
    ByteBuffer dlb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(
            // (# of coordinate values * 2 bytes per short)
            drawOrder.length * 2);
    dlb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    drawListBuffer = dlb.asShortBuffer();
    drawListBuffer.put(drawOrder);
    drawListBuffer.position(0);

    // initialize byte buffer for the color list
    ByteBuffer cb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(
            // (# of coordinate values * 2 bytes per short)
            cubeColor.length * 4);
    cb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    colorBuffer = cb.asFloatBuffer();
    colorBuffer.put(cubeColor);
    colorBuffer.position(0);


    int vertexShader = MyRenderer.loadShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER,
            vertexShaderCode);
    int fragmentShader = MyRenderer.loadShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER,
            fragmentShaderCode);

    // create empty OpenGL ES Program
    mProgram = GLES20.glCreateProgram();

    // add the vertex shader to program
    GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, vertexShader);

    // add the fragment shader to program
    GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, fragmentShader);

    // creates OpenGL ES program executables
    GLES20.glLinkProgram(mProgram);
}

private int mPositionHandle;
private int mColorHandle;

private final int vertexCount = cubeCoords.length / COORDS_PER_VERTEX;
private final int vertexStride = COORDS_PER_VERTEX * 4; // 4 bytes per vertex

public void draw(float[] mvpMatrix) { // pass in the calculated transformation matrix
    // Add program to OpenGL ES environment
    GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgram);

    // get handle to vertex shader's vPosition member
    mPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "vPosition");
    // get handle to fragment shader's vColor member
    mColorHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "vColor");


    // Enable a handle to the cube vertices
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
    // Prepare the cube coordinate data
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, COORDS_PER_VERTEX,
            GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
            vertexStride, vertexBuffer);


    // Set color for drawing the triangle
    //mColorHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "vColor");
    // Enable a handle to the cube colors
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mColorHandle);
    // Prepare the cube color data
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mColorHandle, 4, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 16, colorBuffer);

    // Set the color for each of the faces
    //GLES20.glUniform4fv(mColorHandle, 1, blue, 0);
    //***When I add this line of code above, it can show a cube totally in blue.***

    // get handle to shape's transformation matrix
    mMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "uMVPMatrix");

    // Pass the projection and view transformation to the shader
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mvpMatrix, 0);


    // Draw the cube
    GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, drawOrder.length, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, drawListBuffer);


    // Disable vertex array
    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mColorHandle);
    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mMVPMatrixHandle);
}
```

}

Comment: To be more specific, mColorHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "vColor"); is working fine now, but when I change to mColorHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "vColor");, it display nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the uniform variable vColor declaration from the fragment shader. Define the new per-vertex attribute input variable in the vertex shader, write that value to a varying variable which is output by the vertex shader, and add as a varying input which is read by the fragment shader.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me about this problem. I have seen your solution from other questions. However, I am doing a project on android studio using java, so I am not sure how I can solve this problem in your way. Can you please tell me a little more or some method can be done in android studio?

Comment: This solution is working for me now. Thank you very much!